# Getting Crawled Tweets into a database

Tags: java, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Can anyone tell me how I can go about getting crawled tweets into a database.I crawled the tweets using java. I stored it in a document. I am trying to use xampp to create a database, and store the tweets. I am kinda new to this, and i am trying to learn how to build my own web application. I am stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore Twitter for the moment - you need to understand MySQL integration with PHP first. [Here's one tutorial to start with.](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641) Once you understand database integration, your specific application of that will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at setting up a mysql database and use JDBC to insert into the database programatically.

A helpful tutorial can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm).  I will outline the core steps below.

1. Download and install MySQL on your server.  You may also want to install it on your development machine for testing.  [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).
2. Download the JDBC connector jar.  This is needed to connect to the MySQL database from within Java code.  [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
3. Load the driver that lives in the JDBC connector jar.  This is typically done using the `Class.forName(String)` method.
4. Create a connection in Java and use the Java/Sql interfaces to do what you want with the code.  [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html).